# Android повернуть Background

Tags: android, background, rotation

У меня имеется фон, который необходимо повернуть. Он с указанными match_parent заполняет весь экран. Но при использовании rotation он поворачивается с максимальными размерами экрана. Как его сделать одновременно и повернутым и на весь экран ?

Если что-то не понятно объяснил, то выглядит это примерно так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто-то подумает, что это бессмысленно и можно просто изменить цвет фона на белый*, то вместо белого прямоугольника у меня фон с автозаполнением, который и необходимо повернуть. Это лишь пример:) Спасибо.

Comment: Вот текст после картинки как-раз и не понятен. Ваша ситуация заключается в том что вам нужно повернуть вьюшку определённого размера, для этого вам нужно установить размер этой самой вьюшки, а так как экраны все разныеб значит вам нужно пределить размер вашей вьюшки после измерений. Есть такие методы: getMeashureX() и для У соответственно, и им подобные. Вы можете получить это значение и установить его до того как будете вращать вьюшку. Копайте в эту сторону. Ещё как вариант можно попробовать сделать под 5-ть типов экранов разметки, но не факт что всё будет ок.

Comment: @Valeriy Как раз таки возникающая ситуация, в том что поворачивается вьюшка определенного размера, и является ошибочной. Мне нужно что бы она  просто растягивалась на весь экран(желательно так же просто, как c match_parent) и при этом была повернута.

Comment: Так это совсем другая тема. Transition вам в помощь

Comment: @Valeriy он же для анимации используется, или я чего то не знаю ?

Comment: Да он применяется для анимации, но вы сломали мой мозг, зачем вы тогда хотите поворачивать фон?

Comment: @Valeriy Я понимаю, что скорее всего пишу так, что понятно только мне. Сложно иногда написать то, что в твоей голове. Извиняюсь за то. Все что мне надо, это что бы белый прямоугольник был повернут и за ним ничего синего не было видно, т.е. что бы заполнял весь экран.
Обновил картинку, что бы белый фон не сбивал с толку.

Comment: А почему он у вас под углом, а не вертикально или горизонтально - так задумано? Вы лучше на скринах покажите как есть и как должно быть. И желательно разметку и саму картинку для лучшего понимания.

Comment: @woesss Обновил вопрос. Да, так и задумано, там используется другая картинка. Последние 2 скрина - результат и то, как просто это сделано.

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы узор на бэке был под углом и заполнял весь экран без пустых углов? Такое лучше делать заранее - сделать саму картинку уже такой (повернуть, растянуть, обрезать), а в коде просто поставить готовую.

Comment: @woesss Да, это и нужно. Но с картинкой проблем еще больше. Во-первых не пропадает данная, потому что если указывать размеры вручную, то где то она будет слишком большая, а где то слишком маленькая. Во-вторых, указывая размеры как match_parent, получается тот же результат. В-третьих, с картинкой появляются проблемы с разрешением. А у меня фон - это область, заполняемая через bitmap tileMode. Это все упрощает, но, к сожалению, не решает проблему.

Comment: @woesss Понял, что вы имели ввиду. Делая картинку сразу под углом "во-первых" и "во-вторых" отпадает. Но с разрешением все равно не хочется сталкиваться

Comment: А если сам тайл сделать повёрнутым - при 45 градусах должно получиться вполне нормально. То есть из картинки на вашем скрине вырезаем прямоугольник так, чтобы при размножении пазл складывался в нужную картину. Дальше также заполняем через bitmap tileMode.

Comment: @woesss Проснулся и тоже подумал об этом. Так и решил проблему, спасибо :)